# What is the easiest way to input logs from a certain Docker container to Logstash?

Tags: docker, logstash

I have a Docker container and Logstash.

What is the easiest way to input logs from a certain Docker container to Logstash?

Comment: What have you already tried?  Are there `docker run` command-line options that could be relevant?  Is this a programming question, or more of a system-administration question?

Comment: I've tried this and wasn't successful https://logz.io/blog/docker-logging/ . I'm not an expert in Docker so that's why I'm asking. I have Docker containers and I want to collect logs of a certain one into Logstash. Nothing tricky